# postgresql view join table & has_and_belongs_to_many_association, how to skip callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have model Category, which has recursive parent_id column.
Inside DB i've created sql_view (which readonly) join table (using recursive postgres feature, db automatically maintains all relations, simply "creates" ancestor_id & descendent_id for every related category pair), to flatter hierarchical relationships.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent,
             class_name: 'Category',
             foreign_key: :parent_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :category_ancestors,
                          class_name: 'Category',
                          join_table: 'category_ancestors',
                          foreign_key: :descendent_id,
                          association_foreign_key: :ancestor_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :category_descendents,
                          class_name: 'Category',
                          join_table: 'category_ancestors',
                          foreign_key: :ancestor_id,
                          association_foreign_key: :descendent_id 
end
```

With that, i can use

```
   some_category.category_ancestors
   some_another.category_descendents
```

With only saving parent_id.

The problem is, after removing category, ActiveRecord automatically tries to remove all related records from category_ancestors table, which is readonly and throws exception about this.

Any way to tell ActiveRecord to not try to update join_table records?
I've tried autosave: false, without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `autosave` option for has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Even though I think you are doing it too much complicate, since I use Rails I have not had the need to use database views, have a look at this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins